# Rails through relation with has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, relation, belongs-to

I need to define relation between Packages and Delivers:
1 deliver can has many packages.
But packages can not have delivers. Packages can just belong to Delivers.

Deliver has_many packages, but package can just belongs_to delivers (or to assigments, I do not know).

I should have Assignment table, that store deliver_id and package_id. And when I assign package to deliver - it should create new assignment record

It seems, that I need to use:

```
through: :package_assignments
```

But I do not understand the relation between packages, delivers and assignments.

For now I define package.rb:

```
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :assignments
```

deliver.rb:

```
class Deliver < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :packages, through: :assignments
```

assignment.rb:

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :deliver
  has_many :packages
```

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory: "1 deliver can get many packages": A deliver `has_many` packages. "And 1 package can be assign to just 1 delivery": A delivery `has_one` package?

Comment: You should really rename the model `Delivery` which is a noun. Models should be nouns as they represent things in your business model. `Deliver` is a verb.

Comment: I mean 1 deliver can has many packages. But packages can not have delivers.
I mean it is not about packages has many delivers.

Comment: I renamed as a noun. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean a Package can not have Delivers? Wouldn't a simple `has_many` in the Deliver and a `belongs_to` in the Package be enough? You don't have to create an intermediary `Assignment` table for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In result, I realized many_to_many relation betweeen Package and Deliver through Assignment. It allows to assign, for example, Package to Deliver and it automatically creates Assignment record with package_id and deliver_id.

Deliver model:

```
class Deliver < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :packages, through: :assignments
end
```

Package model:

```
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :delivers, through: :assignments
end
```

Assignment model:

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :deliver
  belongs_to :package
end
```